# What replaces org-latex.el in org-mode version 9?

Tags: org-mode, latex

At work we're running an old version (7.8.1) of org-mode.  In trying to upgrade things to version 9 (specifically 9.1.1), lots of things are breaking.  One particular problem is that our site init file loads org-latex.el.  However, that file has disappeared in version 9.  Can anyone tell me what replaces it?  I realize that the answer might not be simple.  The person who wrote our site-init file has left, and it's not clear why it was doing what it's doing.

Comment: Perhaps `ox-latex.el`?

Comment: Yes, `ox-latex.el` is most probably what needs to be loaded: it is used for LaTeX/PDF exporting. *All* the exporters have been renamed to have an `ox-` prefix. Another, less likely, possibility is `ob-latex.el` which is used for evaluating LaTeX source blocks. Again, all such babel source block evaluators have been renamed to have an `ob-` prefix.